# Automating Google Form with javascript

Tags: javascript, automation, google-forms, queryselector

I have tried to fill in a Google form with required fields (for [example](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc9-nuBCP-_K9IsW9Ql_Tz9CK8uFJGbTur8zub8V7-FWuzbVw/viewform)).
I fill out the text using the 'value' field, but I still receive an error message:
"This is a required question"

This is my javascript code:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput")[0].value = "My answer here"
```

I have also tried clicking, focusing, and changing the error attributes.

Comment: I think it is done that way on purpose, to avoid this type of automatic filling

Comment: So, there isn't a solution?

Comment: I think don't ..

Answer (score 0):

Well i will have two suggestions;

```js
// try with setAttribute function
document
  .querySelectorAll(".quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput")[0]
  .setAttribute("value", "My answer here");

// Maybe more than one element returns?
document
  .querySelectorAll(".quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput")
  .forEach((elm) => (elm.value = "My answer here"));
```

Comment: Still does not work. The text appears but it is beyond the default text. Additionally, when submitting the form, an error message appears.